# Issue with importing specific functions from modules

Tags: python, import

I have two separate modules that I am trying to import specific functions into each other however I keep getting an import error on the functions that are defined within the `helperModule.py` module itself. What am I doing wrong?

**helperModule.py**

```
from utilsModule import startProcess

def getCfgStr():
    pass

def getCfgBool():
    pass

def doSomethingElse():
   startProcess()
```

**utilsModule.py**

```
from helperModule import getCfgStr, getCfgBool

def startProcess():
    a = getCfgStr()
    b = getCfgBool()
    pass
```

Comment: You have a circular import. A cannot import from B which imports from A. You need to refactor.

Comment: I'm confused.  I *thought* the problem was a circular import error, but you claim your first file is called `helperModule.py` but your second imports from a module called `utilshelperModule`.  So is this a case of a circular import error being hidden by a typo, or did you misreport the name of your files?  (Since you only described the error instead of copy-pasting the actual error, it's hard to distinguish between the two.)

Comment: @DSM Same (hence "seems to correspond" in my answer) but I went ahead and answered anyway. I guess if it turns out I'm wrong I'll get the deserved downvotes to show for it.

Comment: @DSM Sorry, copy and paste error!

Comment: @ILostMySpoon If you edit your question with the correction I will add it to my answer to make this less confusing for future readers.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show:

```
from utilsModule import startProcess
```

which corresponds to your `utilsModule.py` where the `startProcess` function is defined. At the top of that file, you show:

```
from helperModule import getCfgStr, getCfgBool
```

which corresponds to your `helperModule.py` where these two functions are defined.

This is a circular import. `utilsModule` imports from `utilshelperModule` which imports from `utilsModule`... you see where I'm going.

You must refactor and have them both import from a third file to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have the functions need the functions they need (on runtime instead of on load time):

```
def getCfgStr():
    pass

def getCfgBool():
    pass

def doSomethingElse():
    from utilsModule import startProcess
    startProcess()

def startProcess():
    from helperModule import getCfgStr, getCfgBool
    a = getCfgStr()
    b = getCfgBool()
```

Or you at least could do the imports as late as possible:

```
def getCfgStr():
    pass

def getCfgBool():
    pass

def doSomethingElse():
   startProcess()

from utilsModule import startProcess
```

and

```
def startProcess():
    a = getCfgStr()
    b = getCfgBool()

from helperModule import getCfgStr, getCfgBool
```

Here, we first put the functions into existence and then provide their global name space with the functions from the other module.

This way, a circular import will probably work, because the imports happen late.

It will nevertheless work, as long as none of the functions affected is used at import time.